# How to remove text area bottom margin in vuetify?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

Hey I have this code:

```
    <v-text-field 
  :rules="rules" 
  v-model="exam.title"
  class="exam-title ma-0 pa-0"
  ></v-text-field>
<v-text-field class="exam-title ma-0 pa-0"></v-text-field>
```

And then it has some margin or padding on the bottom which I cannot remove with a class. How do I get rid of this?

[image]

Problem is fixed by wrapping it inside another element as such:

```
<v-col lg="8">
      <v-text-field 
        v-model="questions.question"
        class="question-container-question"
      ></v-text-field>
</v-col>
```

Comment: `ma-0` should have worked. Can you create a small demo for this using jsfiddle or codesandbox.

Comment: can you share the surrounding code, do you set the height in the parent element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer. When I wrap it in a v-card it seems to remove the padding or margin by default. Strange though that this is the case without a containing component.

Answer (score 9):

I've run into the same problem and found that it helps to set the `hide-details` prop...

```
<v-text-field hide-details class="exam-title">
</v-text-field>
```

https://codeply.com/p/d2SVndXmVi

Comment: Thank you, looks way better!

Comment: yea, but you should mention that every messages/errors will be hidden